# What do I need to user to find and replece words with _ extensions

Tags: text-editor

I have about 20 php documents and I want to change a word I used in all documents which been used over 1000 times. When I tried to replace the word with the _ underscore extensions it does not work!

say I want to change the word example to stackoverflow

when I changed

example to stackoverflow works

example.another.word to stackoverflow works

example-another-word to stackoverflow works

example_another_word to stackoverflow Here is not changing. The problem is I used the word sometimes with uppercase and sometimes with lowercase. I want to change only the first word(example) I'm using notpad++.

Is there any great software can do this job for me.

Comment: just two that come in mind: `netbeans` or `eclipse`..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dreamweaver you can use the search function to search the text throughout the whole website (rather than opening them individually) and then replace the selected text. This does work with the underscore character too.

Use `Control + F`
[image]

Answer (score 0):

SynWrite editor has mass-replace dialog. It can replace needed word for any files set, e.g. in all php-files in a folder. Menu item `Search - Find/replace in files`.